# Can bash make folders, based on a filename, and then move files into the folders?

Tags: bash, directory, mv

On /Desktop/a/ , there is a set of files:

```
DSCN1840.AVI00001.png
DSCN1840.AVI00002.png
DSCN1840.AVI00003.png
DSCN1841.AVI00001.png
```

What I would like is to have the following structure:

```
Desktop/a/DSCN1840/

  DSCN1840.AVI00001.png

  DSCN1840.AVI00002.png

  DSCN1840.AVI00003.png

Desktop/a/DSCN1841/

  DSCN1841.AVI00001.png
```

Comment: as a one-shot retroactive step to make directories and move existing files, or as a proactive step with some piece of software that's downloading these pictures?

Comment: This is curiously similar to [Move files to a folder named by part of their filename](https://superuser.com/q/1373517/354511), but that’s not for Unix&Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a one-shot step, you could loop through all of the files and gather the desired subdirectory name; if that subdirectory doesn't already exist, create it; then move that file into that subdirectory:

```
for f in *.png
do
  subdir=${f%%.*}
  [ ! -d "$subdir" ] && mkdir -- "$subdir"
  mv -- "$f" "$subdir"
done
```

The key part of this is the parameter expansion in `${f%%.*}`, which says to remove the longest matching portion (`%%`) of a period followed by anything, which effectively strips off, for example, the `.AVI00003.png` portions of the filenames, leaving only the leading directory indicator.