# Bash script to move files into folder based on matching ID numbers?

Tags: scripting, directory, mv

On ~/Desktop/a/ , I have files and folders with this pattern:

```
 500 photodir
 Photo 500.jpg
 1000 origindir
 Photo 1000.jpg
```

I would like to have the .jpgs moved into their folders, using the numbers as ID markers:

```
 500 photodir/Photo 500.jpg
 1000 origindir/Photo 1000.jpg
```

This is the code so far:

```
!#/bin/bash/
for f in ~/Desktop/a/*.jpg
do
  base=“${f%Photo*}”
  mv "$f" "$base/"
  mv "$sub/$f"* "$base/$sub/"
done
```

Comment: Ain't this a duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/480803/can-bash-make-folders-based-on-a-filename-and-then-move-files-into-the-folders ?

Comment: @sla3k , not at all.

Comment: @sla3k , Differences are that I do not want to make folders in this case - the folders pre-exist, and instead of a whole chunk of the name being similar, I just want to use the numbers for processing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ~/Desktop/a/
for f in *.jpg; do
  target_part="${f%.jpg}"
  target="${target_part#Photo }"
  mv "$f" -t "${target} "*
done
```

### Explanation

There are two [parameter substitutions](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html) occurring here. Firstly, `target_part="${f%.jpg}"` removes the trailing `.jpg` from the filename, then `target="${target_part#Photo }"` removes the `Photo` (+ space) at the front. This leaves the number in the variable `target`.

Then, you merely move the file to a directory that starts with the number in `target`, i.e. `mv "$f" -t "${target} "*`. This presumes that there is only one filename that starts with each number, and it is a directory.

### Further information

There were a few things wrong with your script. Firstly, the shebang was wrong. Instead of `!#`, it should be `#!`.

Secondly, I'm not sure if just a typo, but the double quote should be with `"`, not `“`.

I'm also not sure why the `*` in your parameter substitution of `${f%Photo*}`, nor what the variable `$sub` referred to (it was never assigned).

Finally, instead of using `~/Desktop/a/*.jpg` for the loop, I preferred to `cd` directly into it, to allow easier parameter substitution.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to mention it, but "photodir" is not a consistent name for all the folders, so I can't use it for a target (some folders are in the form thumbdir, origindir, etc).

Is there a way to just use the ID numbers instead? I tried substituting in ...  mv "$f" "${target_part}" ...

instead, but that's not working.

Comment: Also, regarding your comment ... but the double quote should be with ", not “... How would I type that? I don't see a key for that on my keyboard.

Comment: I fixed the quote issue (was using TextEdit and it automatically converted the quote marks). But still not having luck with the code.

Comment: @user10630009 Please edit your original question to add the full information, then. Add possible directory names, and how the script should select from them. I would recommend not using a text editor that automatically changes what you are typing. (I'm not familiar with Mac software.)

Comment: @user10630009 Answer updated for the new question. Please tag me next time you edit; I don't get a notification otherwise.